# PHP convert formatted string (title + values) to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert this formatted string to multidimensional array but I can't manage to do it.

The goal is to extract titles header (*Dreg Time, FN, SS_ID, MAC, Sector ID, Type, Reason, CMPNT, Basic, Cid*) and associating the corresponding values.

Because in the finality I would need to process the data in the "Reason" column.

**String:**

```
$log = ": mss get dereg_log 2 500



---------- MODEM 2 MAC ---------



Dreg Time                   FN       SS_ID     MAC           Sector ID Type Reason CMPNT Basic Cid

2017/08/29 08:20:39:627   0x4da9f0  8277 00:24:a0:xx:xx:xx         1    2     25     0        86

2017/08/29 07:17:33:478   0x421c02  8238 00:23:a2:xx:xx:xx         1    3     59     0        47

2017/08/29 06:00:43:232   0x340a41  8508 00:23:a2:xx:xx:xx         1    1      6    13       317



Total Deregistrations since sector active in sector 1: 9576

Derigistrations since dreg log last reset in sector 1: 9576



Deregistration Types:

    DEREG_MSS_IMMEDIATE = 0

    DEREG_MSS_DREG_REQ_FROM_AP = 1

    DEREG_MSS_DREG_REQ_FROM_MS = 2

    DEREG_MSS_RNG_RSP_ABORT_FROM_AP = 3

    DEREG_MSS_CONTACT_LOST = 4



---------------------------------

2017-Aug-29 08:31:53.860";
```

**Desired Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Dreg Time] => '2017/08/29 08:20:39:627'
            [FN] => '0x4da9f0'
            [SS_ID] => '8277'
            [MAC] => '00:24:a0:xx:xx:xx'
            [Sector ID] => '1'
            [Type] => '2'
            [Reason] => '25'
            [CMPNT] => '0'
            [Basic Cid] => '86'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Dreg Time] => '2017/08/29 07:17:33:478'
            [FN] => '0x421c02'
            [SS_ID] => '8238'
            [MAC] => '00:23:a2:xx:xx:xx'
            [Sector ID] => '1'
            [Type] => '3'
            [Reason] => '59'
            [CMPNT] => '0'
            [Basic Cid] => '47'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Dreg Time] => '2017/08/29 06:00:43:232'
            [FN] => '0x340a41'
            [SS_ID] => '8508'
            [MAC] => '00:23:a2:xx:xx:xx'
            [Sector ID] => '1'
            [Type] => '1'
            [Reason] => '6'
            [CMPNT] => '13'
            [Basic Cid] => '317'
        )
)
```

**Code tried:**

```
echo '<pre>';
// remove blank lines
$log = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $log);
// remove new lines
$log = preg_replace('/^.+\n.+\n/', '', $log);

$lines = explode( "\n\n", $log );
$return = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $items = explode("\n", $line);
  $return[array_shift($items)] = $items;
}

print_r($return);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [Dreg Time                   FN       SS_ID     MAC           Sector ID Type Reason CMPNT Basic Cid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017/08/29 08:20:39:627   0x4da9f0  8277 00:24:a0:xx:xx:xx         1    2     25     0        86
            [1] => 2017/08/29 07:17:33:478   0x421c02  8238 00:23:a2:xx:xx:xx         1    3     59     0        47
            [2] => 2017/08/29 06:00:43:232   0x340a41  8508 00:23:a2:xx:xx:xx         1    1      6    13       317
            [3] => Total Deregistrations since sector active in sector 1: 9576
            [4] => Derigistrations since dreg log last reset in sector 1: 9576
            [5] => Deregistration Types:
            [6] =>     DEREG_MSS_IMMEDIATE = 0
            [7] =>     DEREG_MSS_DREG_REQ_FROM_AP = 1
            [8] =>     DEREG_MSS_DREG_REQ_FROM_MS = 2
            [9] =>     DEREG_MSS_RNG_RSP_ABORT_FROM_AP = 3
            [10] =>     DEREG_MSS_CONTACT_LOST = 4
            [11] => ---------------------------------
            [12] => 2017-Aug-29 08:31:53.860
        )

)
```

Comment: What `you` have tried ?

Comment: Define "Couldn't manage it" also please.

Comment: I have tried this code : echo '<pre>';

$log = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $log);

$log = preg_replace('/^.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n/', '', $log);

$lines = explode( "\n\n", $log );
$return = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $items = explode("\n", $line);
  $return[array_shift($items)] = $items;
}

print_r($return);

Comment: Please **edit** your question and put the codeyou've tred in your question stating that you tried it and why it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: And what output did you get from your attempt?

Comment: @ADyson I added the print result on the OP Post. In case here is a link https://3v4l.org/mcsuS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was an incomplete attempt, and contained a few errors - e.g. you removed newlines from the log, and then tried split the string based on newlines! Then you tried to split a single line by newline, when clearly a single line cannot, by implication, contain a newline. Also the code just naively ran through each line and added it directly to the array rather than creating an associative array within each index, as shown in the desired output. And lastly it did nothing to try and identify which lines actually contained the desired output.

This will do it:

```
$log = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $log);
$lines = explode( "\n", $log );
$return = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $line = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $line); //condense and standardise the whitespace between each item, so that explode can work.
  $items = explode(" ", $line);
  if (count($items) == 10 && preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}/", $items[0])) //restrict to lines starting with the year, and with the correct number of columns
      $return[] = array(
            "Dreg Time" => $items[0]." ".$items[1],
            "FN" => $items[2],
            "SS_ID" => $items[3],
            "MAC" => $items[4],
            "Sector_ID" => $items[5],
            "Type" => $items[6],
            "Reason" => $items[7],
            "CMPNT" => $items[8],
            "Basic_Cid" => $items[9]
      );
}

 echo "<pre>".var_export($return, true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: well done dude ! Thank you for pointing me in the right way. With yours explanations is more clear. And I learned from your code :)